# Find elements within a certain div and output their respective text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a little div `.form_single_input_field` which contains multiple `.form_single_input_field`s, whose respective text I would like to log. However, the alert will output all values concatenated together, while I would like to have an array of values. How do I achieve that ?

```
$(".form_single_input_field").keyup(function () {

    var actualTarget = $(this).parent();        
    alert(actualTarget.find('.form_single_selection_option').text());


});
```

I know that there is the `.each()` function, but this:

```
$(".form_single_input_field").keyup(function () {

    var actualTarget = $(this).parent();        
    $('.form_single_selection_option').each(function(){
         alert($(this).text());
    });


});
```

would alert all values from ALL `.form_single_selection_option`s in my document, whereas I would like to have only the children and children's children of the selected/current field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
$(".form_single_input_field").keyup(function () {
    var actualTarget = $(this).parent();        
    $('.form_single_selection_option', actualTarget).each(function(){
         alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```